# Problema con Java changeLister ERROR y JSpinner

Tags: java, component, jpanel

veran tengo un problema con un JSpinner, quiero mandar a actualizar un JPnal cada vez que se presiona un botón del JSpinner, he buscado muchos ejemplos y todos son algo así

jspinner.addChangeListenner(this) <--------- ese this a mi suelta un error

[image: Ese es el error que me sale]

Y no sé que hacer para tomar los botones del JSpinner

```
yspinner.setBounds(100, 240, 40, 30);
JFormattedTextField cambiar2 = ((JSpinner.DefaultEditor) yspinner.getEditor()).getTextField();
cambiar2.setEditable(false);
cambiar2.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

xspinner.addChangeListener(this);
add(yspinner);
```

Instancié el JSpiner al inicio de la clase y ahí lo unico que hice fue darle tamaño y desactivar el el textfield que acompaña el JSpinner

[image: Aquí el error completo]

Answer (score 0):

Hay dos motivos por el cual puede marcar un error en `this`

- La primera es porque no has de tener tener implementado `ChangeListener` en la interfaz, para solucionar esto tienes dos formas:

**1. Implementar ChangeListener y agregar el método abstracto:**

```
public class SpinnerDemo3 extends JPanel
                      implements ChangeListener {
protected JSpinner dateSpinner;
...
public SpinnerDemo3() {
    dateSpinner.addChangeListener(this);//this hace referencia al objeto actual
    ...
}

public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
    ...
}
```

**2. Añadir el método directamente:**

```
public class SpinnerDemo3 extends JPanel
                      implements ChangeListener {
protected JSpinner dateSpinner;
...
public SpinnerDemo3() {
    //Listen for changes on the date spinner.
    dateSpinner.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener(){
       public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
          ...
       }
    });//Se crea directamente
}
```

- La segunda es porque no importaste los paquetes correctos, para eso solo comprueba que todos los paquetes deriven de la misma ruta, por ejemplo:

**Correcto ✓:**

```
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;
```

**Incorrecto ✖:**

```
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
```

Comment: No sirve,  me sigue dando errores, igual de la otra forma, me da error en el this, y como dije investigué en todos lados ''esa simple busqueda'' lo hice muchas veces, además si había implementado el changelistenner

YA EDITPE LA IMAGEN CON EL ERROR

Comment: Pido perdón por haberte juzgado mal, al no ver el error lo mas lógico a simple vista era suponer que no tenias el método abstracto en la interfaz, aunque te recomiendo dos cosas para que tus preguntas sean bien recibida por los demás, 1.  Siempre que muestra el error que te genera el código.   2. No pongas imágenes para mostrar código, mejor ponlo en la publicación con formato.